# Is my Canon speedlite really dead?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, repair, hotshoe-flash

My Canon 550ex wouldn't switch on yesterday. Completely dead. Changed the batteries (twice). Still nothing, no indication of life. It was fine last time I used it about a week ago.

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Can analysis be worthwhile? Is the speedlight really dead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After trying as few things and playing around with the flash with no success, I found the following [thread](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1010792) on the web.

The advice given is :

> Rub all the battery contacts very briskly with a clean rag that is
>   just ever so slightly damp.

I actually works! To rub the terminals inside the battery compartment I wrapped a thin, slightly damp rag around the eraser end of a pencil and gave it a few spins. The terminals didn't look corroded or damaged. Afterwards the speedlite switched on, good as new.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer. Congratulations on having fixed the issue with your flash!

Comment: Sometimes rubbing all the contacts with the eraser end of a pencil also works at cleaning off the crud.

Comment: as per the advice cleaned the contacts with damp cloth and pencil and switched on and off with batteries removed seems to work ok now

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I saw (can't find the original link anymore), was to take the batteries out and switch on and off again. Apparently this 'resets' the electronics.

I don't know if this actually works. I'm just adding it here as something to try for people who search this question.

Answer (score 1):

All I know is I was just about to go out and buy a new Flash Gun for my 5D MkIII as both my flashes had failed, the problem I realised was I hadn't used my Flashes for a couple of years, they were not well used but both my 580EX ii and my 430EX failed to even show a glimmer of a spark. Then I read about cleaning the contacts with a slightly damp cloth wrapped around a pencil rubber(eraser). I am now the proud owner of two working flashes, and a few hundred pounds better off.